# Find open files in Java heapdump using memory analyzer

Tags: java, eclipse-memory-analyzer

I have a java heapdump which I've opened in Memory Analyzer. Is there some way in memory analyzer (mat) to query for open file handles? I would like to identify exactly which class opened the file and holds an active reference to the file.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to replace the implementation of `java.io` with one that tracks open files in the way you want, and rerun the program?

Comment: I may look at that if I can't use the running VM or a heapdump to identify the open files.

Comment: You can look for instances of `FileDescriptor` but I never had much success with that. This is usually much more helpful: http://file-leak-detector.kohsuke.org/